# Is there a term for a storytelling style where a passage is repeated with more and more detail?

Tags: creative-writing

I've been writing some things in this style and I'm not entirely sure if there's a term for it - I'm sure I'm not the first person to think of something like this and I'd like to read some more about it to get better at it.

Something like:

"It was a cold night."

Followed by another passage, followed by:

"It was a cold night, for the month of july, which was rather unusual."

And so on.

Comment: It is called a Cumulative Tale.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_tale

Comment: Wetcircuit, you should offer that as a reply.

Answer (score 3):

[Wetcircuit](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/23253/wetcircuit) gave a perfect answer in their comment, but I want to get this question off of the unanswered list. As mentioned, these are "[cumulative tales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_tale)," which are well-suited for tragic tales as they depend on progressively accumulating detail that concludes suddenly. The German tale "[Little Louse and Little Flea](https://www.pitt.edu/~dash/type2022.html)" is a fine example, ending with the "cumulative" summary and the traditionally sobering denouement:

> Little louse has burned herself to death.
>       Little flea is crying.
>       Little door is creaking.
>       Little broom is sweeping.
>       Little cart is running.
>       Little manure pile is burning.
>       Little tree is shaking.
>
> "Oh," said the spring, "then I will begin to flow," and it began to flow furiously. And everything drowned in the water: the girl, the little tree, the little manure pile, the little cart, the little broom, the little door, the little flea, and the little louse, all together.

*A Companion to the Fairy Tale* includes the chapter ["Catch if you can: The Cumulative Tale,"](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=TzXFvKeFJu0C&oi=fnd&pg=PA123&dq=cumulative+tale&ots=x_RW810xHj&sig=pPUdS88HHxXzwVT0u4WsWYXGZJ8#v=onepage&q&f=false) which provides some interesting commentary on the structure and history of the cumulative tale, although only a portion of the chapter is freely available:

> Rather like a constructed tower of cards, the tale extends itself until it reaches the inevitable collapse – at its best, a resounding memory-racking crescendo of accumulations, which then abruptly stops. With the cumulative tale, the repetitive pattern takes precedence over the plot or, some might say, *is* the plot. Essentially, the tale exists to add to or multiply itself via those accumulations.

Comment: I was thinking something less "fairy-tale" and more something that slowly delivers more details about a scene in a repetitive manner, details which may slowly change the tone or context of the passage.

Comment: From my understanding, a decent example of this might be the classic short story “The Lottery.” It describes a very brief sequence that is contextually revealed to be different (maybe even the opposite) than it seems at the beginning. This can be characterized as a gradual [tonal (or rhetorical) shift](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ToneShift). If this is a severe enough shift, it might even be classified as a genre shift. I’m struggling to find a more specific term for what you’re describing – it might be that you’re looking for something more memory-oriented?